# Set screen lock schedule on Fedora 34

Tags: linux, fedora, screen-lock

Is there a screen time feature either built in to Fedora 34 or available as an app like in [elementary os](https://elementary.io/#:%7E:text=Screen%20Time%20%26%20Limits)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable working with source files and the terminal, you may edit `/etc/security/time.conf`

Owing to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054444/force-ubuntu-to-log-out-at-a-specific-time) and the modified script by elementary os I was able set my schedules and rules. The script as modified by elementary is given below. It's a bit of an overkill, but the OP was about screen time apps.

```
## PANTHEON_PARENTAL_CONTROLS_START
*;*;sampleUser1;Wk0800-2300
*;*;sampleUser2;Wk0800-2300
## PANTHEON_PARENTAL_CONTROLS_END
```

This is slightly different what the OP mentioned, so I won't mark this as an answer.

This disallows the specified accounts to login outside the listed time, during weekdays from 8 A.M. to 11 P.M. according to the time on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The Screen Time feature is not yet provided in Fedora 34, but it is expected to be developed by the GNOME project and provided with the Parental Controls application. You can monitor the [issue #10](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pwithnall/malcontent/-/issues/10) of the `malcontent` GitLab repository to track the development of the feature.

The [tentative design](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/ParentalControls) included:

> Restrictions: …
>
> - Set daily limit for screen time; prevent the child from using the computer once this has been exceeded
>
> Components to the design: …
>
> - [Screen time settings](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/SystemSettings/ScreenTime) - where a child can see information about their usage, and how much screen time they have left

The Parental Controls are already in the main repository of Fedora:

```
$ dnf search parental
Останню перевірку на застарілість метаданих було виконано 8:56:35 тому, вт, 07-вер-2021 15:21:11 +0300.
========================= Відповідник Резюме: parental =========================
malcontent.x86_64 : Parental controls implementation
malcontent-control.x86_64 : Parental Controls UI
malcontent-pam.x86_64 : Parental Controls PAM Module
malcontent-tools.x86_64 : Parental Controls Tools
```

There is even a PAM module to prevent users from logging in beyond a scheduled time frame:

```
$ dnf info malcontent-pam
Останню перевірку на застарілість метаданих було виконано 0:00:06 тому, ср, 08-вер-2021 07:37:35 +0300.
Доступних пакунків
Назва        : malcontent-pam
Версія       : 0.10.0
Випуск       : 2.fc34
Архітектура  : x86_64
Розмір       : 22 k
Джерело      : malcontent-0.10.0-2.fc34.src.rpm
Сховище      : fedora
Резюме       : Parental Controls PAM Module
Адреса       : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pwithnall/malcontent/
Ліцензування : LGPLv2+
Опис         : This package contains a PAM module which prevents logins for users who have
             : exceeded their allowed computer time.
```

But the application does not have this functionality yet.

[image: The screenshot of the available Parental Control settings like restricting application access.]

At the moment, there is only a [design mock-up](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Teams/Design/settings-mockups/blob/master/parental-controls/parental-controls.png) of the screen time feature:

> [image: The design mock up, where it is possible to restrict how much time the child uses the computer.]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give such a detailed answer. I will look forward to this feature!